# What's the differences between observers and listeners in polymer?

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

If I set the property as follow:

```
properties: {
    myProp: {
        type: Object,
        notify: true,
        observer: '_onChangedByObserver',
    }
},
listeners: {
    'my-prop-changed': '_onChangedByListener'
}
```

When I run the code, both `_onChangedByObserver` and `_onChangedByListener` are called whenever `myProp` changed.

So how to determine which to used?

ps: I want to tell whether the change comes from external consumer or internal assignment. What should I do?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Observers are called when the value of the property is changed. Listeneres are event handler for all kind of events, not only property changes. For observers to work you don't need to set `notify: true`, if you want a listener to be called on property change, this is necessary. Also the method signature differs. Observers get passed the new and the old value while listeners get an event with the new value in the details field.

I don't think there is a way to tell what caused the change in both cases.

Comment: Thx for the reply! It really helps. Can you please also look at this plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/ZTONoYhYRIXqEijvfU3v?p=preview  , Is it true that 'prop-changed' event will NOT be fired when change is made by data-binding? Otherwise why the widget-b cannot detect the 'value-changed' event in the listener (when changed is make from outter code)?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't able to figure out from your Plnkr what doesn't work as expected, could you please remove everything that works as expected and  only keep what doesn't work?

Comment: Looks like you are setting the `value` on `a` and expect the listener on `b` to be notified. If you actually want to set the value on `b` you should consider that there was a bug recently related to properties named `value` and that you need to use `.set('value', 'a1')` instead of `.value = 'a1'`(I use Polymer only from Dart and there are a few differences. I'm not absolutely sure when `.set()` is or is not necessary in JS). http://plnkr.co/edit/iMTwLuBIlFdfFoHptyGe?p=preview

Comment: I test it. Property 'value' does work in my chrome. The event 'value(x)-changed' will be fired either using .set() or .value = 'a1' WHEN change value directly on widget-b. If I change on widget-a, the value will be passed to widget-b correctly, observer is invoked, but NO 'value-changed' event fired, though the 'value' did 'changed'. But thanks for all the help. I am more clear now.

Comment: Ok, missed that binding. I guess I understand the problem now. Might be https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/3077